# creating comment box; text body does not get forwarded

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a comment section on a website. The page I am using to attempt this is at the necessities only.  My problem is that the comment body does not get forwarded to the table I have set up.  The date gets sent and stored, though.  I have posted the code below.  I have been looking over this code for a while and am starting to get frustrated.  Research yielded no answers.  I am turning this over to you guys as my last resort.  Thanks for any help or direction.

Front end code:

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td><strong>Test Sign Guestbook </strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addguestbook.php">
    <td>`enter code here`
    <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">Comment</td>
        <td valign="top">:</td>
        <td><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </form>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td><strong><a href="viewguestbook.php">View Notebook</a> </strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

back end code:

```
<?php
$host=***** 
$username=***** 
$password=**** This is all 100% correct, for sure.
$db_name=*****
$tbl_name=****

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$comments=$comment;
$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(comment, datetime)VALUES('$comments', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful 
if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>"; 
    // link to view guestbook page
    echo "<a href='viewguestbook.php'>View guestbook</a>";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  retrieve the `comments` either using `$_GET` or `$_POST` method. But since your using `POST` method you need to retrieve your value like this:

```
$comments=$_POST['comment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using:

```
$comments = $_POST['comment'];
```

Another thing that will make your life a lot easier is the built in function called NOW(), more info about this function can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Overall, just be sure to create a variable that is linking to the outcome or the 'post' of your form, this variable can then be used later on, i.e. when you need to insert things into databases.